# how to increase ideal timeout in "k8s exec -ti pod --bash" command

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, microk8s

In K8s, I am getting logged-out from the bash after 15 seconds, Is there any way to increase this ideal timeout.

```
Kite@xxx-qa-n01:/deployment$ time kubectl exec -ti elasticsearch-0 -n pprod -- bash
[elasticsearch@elasticsearch-0 ~]$
real    0m15.167s
user    0m0.108s
sys 0m0.057s
Kite@xxx-qa-n01:/deployment$
```

Answer (score -1):

The timeout for the exec can be set using the flag **--request-timeout** along with the command as below

```
kubectl exec -it pod_name bash --request-timeout=0 -n test
```

Please refer [kubectl flags](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) for more details.

```
--request-timeout string           The length of time to wait before giving up on a single server request. Non-zero values should contain a corresponding time unit (e.g. 1s, 2m, 3h). A value of zero means don't timeout requests. (default "0")
```

Comment: Hello, @user87005 Does this answer help you?

Comment: This is incorrect though. `--request-timeout` is the Kube API request timeout. If `kubectl exec` itself is successful, that is -- the pod exists and the command can be executed against it, the timeout won't happen.